# How do I know if std::map insert succeeded or failed?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stl

I have a map in a multithreaded app mapping a class called uuid to pointer.
What I want to know if an insert operation succeeded for failed.

e.g.

```
_mymap.insert(hint, MyMap::value_type(entry.uuid, itemptr));
```

Does it throw an exception or something if it fails?

Comment: @Armen, Tried that. I couldn't found any examples that show it.  All the examples just assume insert succeeds.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In fact the insert method which takes a hint parameter does not return whether the insert succeeded or not. One way to check if insert actually happened would be to check the size of the map before and after insertion. If it is the same, then insert has failed (i.e. the key was already present). I know it sounds ugly, but that's the most efficient way I could come up with. In fact I believe that there is no compelling reason that the insert with a hint should not return a pair (including the bool) just like the regular non-hint insert does. But once it has been specified in an older standard, it is very hard to change, since it is a breaking change, which the C++ community mostly resents.

#### Original (wrong) answer

[See this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/)

... returns a pair, with its member `pair::first` set to an iterator pointing to either the newly inserted element or to the element that already had its same value in the map. The `pair::second` element in the pair is set to true if a new element was inserted or false if an element with the same value existed.

The link also contains an example

For example:

```
if(mp.insert(make_pair(key, value)).second == false)
{
   cout << "Insertion failed. Key was present"
}
```

Comment: In fact, this is incorrect. The insert() method with a hint parameter does not return a pair, but just an iterator.

Comment: **IMPORTANT**: If you just insert an element **WITHOUT** the hint parameter, use the answer in the *[See this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/)*. The original answer was wrong because it is for the case where we don't need the hint parameter, but the poster of the question need the hint. The original answer is **NOT** wrong if we don't need the hint, which is often the case.

Comment: Concerning the reason for the hint-ed version of `insert` returning an `iterator` instead of a `pair`, Nicolai M. Josuttis, in his "The C++ Standard Library" (both 1st and 2nd versions), justifies it by saying that this way _you have one `insert` function that has the same interface for all container types_ defined in the STL (`vector`, `deque`, `list`, `set`, `multiset`, `map`, `multimap`).

Comment: Depending on your definition of failure, you might  need `insert_or_assign` (c++17 standard) whose returned boolean (if the version without the hint is used) differentiates between the insertion case (true) and the assignment case (false). See the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign)

Answer (score 8):

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> map;
map m;
std::pair<map::iterator,bool> result = m.insert(std::make_pair("hi", 42));
```

result.second contains what you want

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you mean by failed or succeeded.

`std::map::insert` succeeds when it inserts the new element, otherwise it returns an iterator to an already existing element.

`std::map::insert` fails if there is not enough memory to insert a new element and throws `std::bad_alloc`.

Answer (score 3):

> The first insert member function
>   returns a pair whose bool component
>   returns true if an insertion was made
>   and false if the map already contained
>   an element whose key had an equivalent
>   value in the ordering, and whose
>   iterator component returns the address
>   where a new element was inserted or
>   where the element was already located.
>
> To access the iterator component of a
>   pair pr returned by this member
>   function, use pr.first, and to
>   dereference it, use *(pr.first). To
>   access the bool component of a pair pr
>   returned by this member function, use
>   pr.second.
>
> The second insert member function, the
>   hint version, returns an iterator that
>   points to the position where the new
>   element was inserted into the map.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81ac0zkz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Ok, that's pretty hard to understand. Can you give me an example. MS doesn't actually have one that I can see.

Comment: I think your link is wrong. It points to a page with the title "System.Collections.Generic Namespace".

Comment: Yes and I'd like to point out I'm using gcc under linux. Hopefully all STLs are created equal?

Comment: @Matt H: Yes, the STL is standardized.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would throw one of the exceptions used in the STL, e.g. when out of memory. That is in case of **failure**.

Or were you also interested in knowing whether the element was already contained in the instance?

Answer (score -1):

It is also possible to know wether a pair was inserted or found in a map after insertion with hint (much faster).

Insert with hint method another pair of the same first, and of a second that you are sure is not in the map ( like -1 for a map of positive second int). If the iterator returned has this impossible value, it has been newly inserted, if not it was found in the map. The iterator returned may then be changed.
Example : to insert pairs p (2,4) and p (6, 5) in the map<int, int> m ((0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)).

```
int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  std::pair<int, int> tmp [3] = {
    std::pair<int, int> (0, 1),
    std::pair<int, int> (2, 3),
    std::pair<int, int> (4, 5)
  };
  std::map<int, int> m ((std::pair<int, int>*) tmp, (std::pair<int, int>*) &tmp [3]);

  std::cout << "initial map == ";
  std::for_each (m.begin (), m.end (), [] (const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << "->" << p.second << "   ";
  });
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  {
    //insertion of a pair of first already in map
    std::cout << "insertion of pair 1 == std::pair<int, int> (2, 4) from second iterator" << std::endl;
    std::map<int, int>::iterator ihint (m.begin ()), k (ihint); ++ihint;
    std::pair<int, int> pfoo (2, -1);
    k = m.insert (ihint, pfoo);
    if (k->second == -1) {
      std::cout << "\tthe pair was inserted" << std::endl;
      k->second = 4;
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "\ta pair with such a first was in the map" << std::endl;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "m after insertion of pair 1 == ";
  std::for_each (m.begin (), m.end (), [] (const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << "->" << p.second << "   ";
  });
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  {
    //insertion of a pair of first not in map
    std::cout << "insertion of pair 2 == std::pair<int, int> (6, 5) from third iterator" << std::endl;
    std::map<int, int>::iterator ihint (m.begin ()), k (ihint); ++ihint; ++ihint;
    std::pair<int, int> pfoo (6, -1);
    k = m.insert (ihint, pfoo);
    if (k->second == -1) {
      std::cout << "\tthe pair was inserted" << std::endl;
      k->second = 5;
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "\ta pair with such a first in the map" << std::endl;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "m after insertion of pair 2 == ";
  std::for_each (m.begin (), m.end (), [] (const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << "->" << p.second << "   ";
  });
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

outputs :
initial map == 0->1   2->3   4->5

insertion of pair 1 == std::pair<int, int> (2, 4) from second iterator

a pair with such a first was in the map

m after insertion of pair 1 == 0->1   2->3   4->5

insertion of pair 2 == std::pair<int, int> (6, 5) from third iterator

the pair was inserted

m after insertion of pair 2 == 0->1   2->3   4->5   6->5

Comment: As my answer was downvoted with no explanation, I added initial map construction, inserted two pairs (one in the map, one not) and print hint insertion results. Using preincrementation, faster than post incrementation. The map I am using is not anymore called "map", but "m", so it wont confuse people "using namespace std", but just "m". Modification of foo iterator is just performed in case of insertion

Comment: I've not downvoted you, but your answer is for sure not easly readable (I'm talking about the text, not the code).

Comment: my example explains how to kow wether a pair was inserted or retrieved in a map using insertion with hint