# Problem compiling stl map insert

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stl

I'm having trouble compiling the following code:

```
typedef std::map<mUUID, block_ptr_t> BlockMap;
BlockMap _store;

std::pair< BlockMap::iterator, bool > it;
it = _store.insert(hint, std::make_pair(entry.block_uid, block));
```

The error is:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘it = BlockStore::_store.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert [with _Key = mUUID, _Tp = Block*, _Compare = std::less<mUUID>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const mUUID, Block*> >](lb, ((const std::pair<const mUUID, Block*>&)(& std::pair<const mUUID, Block*>(((const std::pair<mUUID, Block*>&)((const std::pair<mUUID, Block*>*)(& std::make_pair(_T1, _T2) [with _T1 = mUUID, _T2 = Block*](block))))))))’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_pair.h:68: note: candidates are: std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const mUUID, Block*> >, bool>& std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const mUUID, Block*> >, bool>::operator=(const std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const mUUID, Block*> >, bool>&)
```

It seems to be related to the assignment because if I don't assign it to "it" it compiles without error.

Comment: What is the type of `_store`, and what does `_store.insert` actually return?

Comment: _store is actually a BlockMap type sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `insert` that takes a hint returns only an iterator, not a pair.

Comment: Dang, you're right.  How do I get it to use the hint and also find out if the insert succeeded?

Comment: I think all you can do is to check whether `_store.size` has increased.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your example is incomplete - _store is defined nowhere.

Second, it seems you are trying to assign an iterator to a std::pair - why do you need a pair, anyway?

The following should work, provided that _store is of type BlockMap:

`BlockMap::iterator it;

it = _store.insert(std::make_pair(entry.block_uid, block));`

Comment: I need to know if insert succeeded, if it didn't then I want to get access to the element that is already in _store at that position.  i.e.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106170/how-do-i-know-if-stdmap-insert-succeeded-or-failed

Comment: Looks like I can't do it with a hint and have to use the version that returns a pair.

Comment: If you only need the iterator pointing to the element, you can use the version with the hint, since it will return an iterator pointing to the existing element if there was any - see
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/

Comment: No, I am inserting an element with the same id. If it already exists I want the version that was already in there.  If insert succeeded it seems that it still returns an iterator, but it's to the element I just inserted.  Kind of pointless in some ways.  Pity there isn't a hint version that can return pair.  Oh well, it shouldn't hurt performance really.